# GroupBox contain controls,how to get the names of those controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Im using GroupBox Control on my Form Page(WinForms).

The GroupBox contain five controls(RadioButtons).

Any idea how can I get the names and the states of controls 
inside GroupBox Control?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) to find and cast your `RadioButtons` in the GroupBox:

```
var radioButtons = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>();
foreach (RadioButton rb in radioButtons)
{
    bool state = rb.Checked;
    string name = rb.Name;
}
```

Comment: And in WPF applications? There are no "Controls" :(

Answer (score 1):

```
       var grpBox = new GroupBox();
        if (grpBox.HasChildren)
        {
            var name = grpBox.Controls[0].Name;
        }
```

Comment: He also needs the state, which means they need to be of type RadioButton.

Comment: I think he added that point letter, when I answered it was for just Name :(